# How to append an auto-incremented integer to output file?

Tags: windows, powershell

If I want to output a file `hello.txt`, how can I:

- check for existence
- append `-1` at the end if it does
- check that `hello-1.txt` doesn't exist
- loop until `hello-{integer}.txt` isn't found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another possibility:

```
if ( test-path hello.txt ) 
 {
  $i=0
  do { $i++ }
  until ( -not ( test-path "hello-$i.txt" ) )
  $filename = "hello-$i.txt"
 }
 else { $filename = 'hello.txt' }

 $filename
```

Answer (score 1):

This code should fulfill all of your requirements. See in-line comments for details. Let me know if it needs any modifications.

```
# 1. Check for existence of hello.txt
$FilePath = "$PSScriptRoot\hello.txt";
if (Test-Path -Path $FilePath) {
    # 2. Rename the file to "hello-1.txt" if it exists
    Move-Item -Path $FilePath -Destination $FilePath.Replace('hello.txt', 'hello-1.txt');
}

# 3. Test that hello-1.txt doesn't exist
$FilePath2 = "$PSScriptRoot\hello-1.txt";
Test-Path -Path $FilePath2;

# 4. Loop until hello-*.txt doesn't exist
while (Get-ChildItem -Path $PSScriptRoot\hello-[0-9].txt) {
    # Loop
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 5;
    Write-Host -Object 'Looping ...';
}
```